# How to identify an android emulator (AVD) using ADB

Tags: android, command-line, adb, emulation, device

I use the emulator AVD and i have 3 android :

- First name Android : test
- Second name Android : test1
- Third name Android : test2

I launch the first and second android with command line :

```
emulator -avd test
emulator -avd test1
```

And after, when i use this command line :

```
avd devices
```

I have

> List of devices attached 
>   emulator-5556   device 
>   emulator-5554   device

How i can identify my android emulator with adb (only command line)? 
If it's impossible, how I can know if my device is started with "emulator" (only  command line) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing a `TELNET` to the `AVD`

```
emulator -avd test
emulator -avd test1

avd devices

List of devices attached 
emulator-5556 device 
emulator-5554 device

telnet localhost 5554
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
...
OK
avd name
test1
```

Comment: Kindly up-vote and accept my answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Any other simple way?